# VBA Excel - DropDown list with 2 key fields

Tags: excel, vba

I have been struggling with this requirement for a time.

I have 2 Excel Sheets as follow : 
Sheet1

[image]

Sheet2:

[image]

The requirement is to get Batch lis in dropdown list based on Key values from MAT field and plant field from Sheet1.

I have done it with additional column "KEY", where I use merge for values for both fields "MAT" and "Plant" and using data validation with INDIRECT

[image]

But I want to do this without additional column and without of merging key values.

Comment: Can't understand the relation between values of "plant" in sheets 1 and 2. Why to the MAT/PLANT pair M1/AE11 batchs B1 and B2 are assigned, since there are no plants AE11 in Sheet1?

Comment: Sorry bad screenshot. There is also AE11 plant on first Sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following.

```
Private Sub LoadData()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim lLastRowSheet1 As Long, lLastRowSheet2 As Long, i As Long
    Dim TheCombination As String
    Dim TheBatch As String
    Dim TheOptions() As String

    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    lLastRowSheet1 = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lLastRowSheet2 = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'Add elements to dictionary
    For i = 2 To lLastRowSheet1
        TheCombination = ws1.Cells(i, 1).Value & ws1.Cells(i, 2).Value 'combine MAT and PLANT
        TheBatch = ws1.Cells(i, 3).Value

        If Not dict.Exists(TheCombination) Then 'If key does not exist, add it
            dict.Add TheCombination, TheBatch
        Else
            TheItems = Split(dict.Item(TheCombination), ",")
            If Not IsInArray(TheBatch, TheItems) Then
                dict.Item(TheCombination) = dict.Item(TheCombination) & "," & ws1.Cells(i, 3).Value 'Add Batch if not already added
            End If
        End If
    Next

    For i = 2 To lLastRowSheet2
        TheSheet2Combination = ws2.Cells(i, 1).Value & ws2.Cells(i, 2).Value
        TheOptions = Split(dict.Item(TheSheet2Combination), ",")
        With ws2.Cells(i, 3).Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:=Join(TheOptions, ",")
        End With
    Next
End Sub


Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1)
End Function
```